# Can I create a comparative each block in Svelte to retain my index?

Tags: svelte

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to use this each block.
Right now the index does not work as I want it to because the entire answers get their index before some get removed.

```
{#each answers as answer, i}
    {#if poll.uuid == answer.pollid}
        <div class="answer" on:click={vote(answer.uuid)}>
            <div class="persentage" style="width: {getprosent(poll.uuid, i)}%"></div>
            <span>{answer.answer}</span>
            <div class="votes">
            <span>{votes.filter(vote => vote.pollid == answer.uuid).length}</span>  
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

Is there any way I can compare like seen above without the whole array getting an index?

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand. However I see somethings that look a bit different that how you would generally do it. In your `on:click` when you just write `vote(answer.uuid)`that function is gonna run even though you are not pressing it. You should instead write `on:click={() => vote(answer.uuid)}`. Apart from that, depending on if i understand your question, you might consider giving the #each block a key, like `{#each answers as answer, i (i)}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `answers`, like:

```
const pollAnswers = answers.filter(answer => poll.uuid == answer.pollid)

{#each pollAnswers as answer, i}
```