# Can you make the index only count for data that pass through an if statement in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

My question was poorly worded, but I'll try again.

```
{#each answers as answer, index}
{#if poll.uuid == answer.pollid}
        <div class="answer" on:click={vote(answer.uuid)}>
            <div class="persentage" style="width: {getprosent(poll.uuid, index)}%"></div>
            <span>{answer.answer}</span>
            <div class="votes">
            <span>{votes.filter(vote => vote.pollid == answer.uuid).length}</span>  
            </div>
        </div>
{/if}
{/each}
```

Basically I want to use the index of only the "each", but only the one that pass through that if statement. So in my code I have different polls, and each one of those polls have answers. I only want to display the answers that have the same pollid as the polls have uuid. This works for displaying the correct answers to the correct polls. Although I want to access the index to only the answers that show up. Now for every poll the same indexes are given and indexes are gives to answers that don't show up.

I'm new and this I feel very stupid, but is there a way for me to give the corrent 0, 1, 2, 3 but only to the answers that pass through the if statement.

Comment: Still not completely sure what you mean, but let me try.
You should filter already in the each block like this:
`{#each answers.filter(ans => ans.pollid === poll.uuid) as answer, index}
    <div>....`
Then you don't need the {#if} block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a comparative each block in Svelte to retain my index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66997032/can-i-create-a-comparative-each-block-in-svelte-to-retain-my-index)

Comment: Next time, you can just edit your previous question rather than post a new question

Comment: Ok! I will. I've never posted here before. Thank you so much for helping me even though it must be such a nuisance! Love y'all! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me write my comment out. You can do the following:

```html
{#each answers.filter((ans) => poll.uuid === ans.pollid) as answer, index}
        <div class="answer" on:click={vote(answer.uuid)}>
            <div class="persentage" style="width: {getprosent(poll.uuid, index)}%"></div>
            <span>{answer.answer}</span>
            <div class="votes">
            <span>{votes.filter(vote => vote.pollid == answer.uuid).length}</span>  
            </div>
        </div>
{/each}
```